# Rouding failing for whole numbers in Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

How to round an whole number to one decimal position?I have one float field in in my table in sql server 2012 and I need to show that value in 1 decimal position for eg.

I have one value as 5 I need to show it as 5.0

Comment: This should be done in the display/formatting/ui layer

Comment: Try `CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), YourColumn)` where 10 is the total number of positions it can contain. You can adjust this accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you have only whole numbers, there is no point of rounding-off rather concatenating `.0` to your result. But, if you are expecting floating point numbers along with the  whole numbers and you want all of them to be shown as 1 floating point numbers then you may try this-

```
DECLARE @Var FLOAT
SET @Var=5
SELECT ROUND(CAST(@Var AS DECIMAL(15,1)),1)

SET @Var=5.19
SELECT ROUND(CAST(@Var AS DECIMAL(15,1)),1)
```

Result will be `5.0` and `5.2` respectively.